# Jenkins replay feature

Tags: jenkins

I would like to use Replay feature. The documentation said:

1) Can be called multiple times on the same run

2) Can also be called on Pipeline runs that are still in-progress

What is the difference with these two points? Could you explain me better?

Answer (score 1):

1) Each 'Build' (or 'Run') has some configuration (like parameters of the build for 'Build with parameters') that sometime you want to reuse in Replay. You can launch multiple Replay on the same 'Build'. Each of the Replayed Build will get the same parameters as the original one.

2) You are able to launch Replay also on the 'Build' that is still in-progress. It is irrelevant for Replayed 'Build' because once launched, the original 'Build' already updated its object in Jenkins master with all that will be of use for Replay.

Comment: About point 2, Builds are "still not in progress" or "still in progress" as the documentation said?